# intellij IDEA - Can't access DB Navigator - Operation not supported

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

When I want to add a new table in IntelliJ IDEA by right click and choose New Table..;

[image: IDE message]

It says that the operation of creating a new table is not supported yet. I'm using MySql for the database.

When I was watching some YouTube tutorials, they had that feature, but I can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded that plugin by any chance, Database Navigator?

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Just be advised that some plugins, possibly this one too, work 100% with the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ, while the Community edition has limits on which plugins you can use.